# How to retrieve web site favicons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image, favicon

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.0.9 and I would like to retrieve the `favicon.ico` image of each web site for which I set a link.

That is, if in my application I set the `http://www.facebook.com/` URL I would like to retrieve the Facebook' icon and use\insert that in my web pages. Of course I would like to do that also for all other web sites.

How can I retrieve `favicon.ico` icons from web sites in an "*automatic*" way (with "automatic" I mean to search for a favicon in a web site and get the link to it - I think no because not all web sites have a favicon named exactly 'favicon.ico'. I would like to recognize that in an "automatic" way)?

P.S.: What I would like to make is something like Facebook makes when to add a link\URL in your Facebook page: it recognizes the related web site logo and then appends that to the link\URL.

Comment: Just a thought, are you sure there's no copyright problem with that?

Comment: @Johnny5 - I do not know that for sure, but I do not use favicons as my web site logo (I just insert those in my web pages) and I think favicons are public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With javascript (jQuery), like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aX8T4/

Comment: Can be the best way to use jQuery to achieve these things?

Comment: Unfortunately that only works if the favicon is located in the domain root. Some websites do something like this though: `<link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />`

Answer (score 3):

http://getfavicon.appspot.com/ works great for fetching favicons. Just give it the url for the site and you'll get the favicon back:

http://g.etfv.co/http://www.google.com

Comment: Thanks. This is the only answer that doesn't assume the icon is located at "www.rooturl.com/favicon.ico"

Comment: Since getfavicon has closed down, here's an alternative way: [https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2):

Recently I have written some similar solution.

If we want find favicon url, that can be not only `.ico` file and can be not in the root, we should parse target site html.

In Ruby on Rails, I have used [nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/) gem for html parsing. 
First we parse all meta tags where `itemprop` attribute contains `image` keyword. It is necessary in situations where target site used https://schema.org/WebPage template, that more modern technology than just `link` tag.

If we found it, we can use `content` attribute as favicon url. But we should check it for really URL existence, just to be sure.

If we can't found some meta tags, then we search for standard `link` tags, where `rel` attribute contains `icon` keyword. This is W3C standard situation (https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon)

And some code of my solution:

```
require 'open-uri'

def site_icon_link site
    icon_link = nil
    url = nil
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(site))
    metas = doc.css("meta[itemprop*=image]")

    if metas.any? 
        url = metas.first.attributes['content'].value
    else 
        links = doc.css("link[rel*=icon]")
        if links.any? 
            url = links.first.attributes['href'].value
        end
    end

    if url =~ URI::regexp
        icon_link = url
    elsif (site + url) =~ URI::regexp
        icon_link = site + url
    end

    icon_link

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I missed your question ...

you want to grab a favicon from another site and make it yours?

if that's what you want, you can get directly from the home icon and save it in your public folder.

thus: `www.facebook.com` favicon: `www.facebook.com/favicon.ico`

take that image and save with the name favicon in your public folder

done it should be sufficient

---

if you want it dinamicaly you can use jquery, but if you want that static you can put a image tag pointing to: [root url of the website]/favicon.ico

like this: `<%= image_tag "#{website.url}/favicon.ico" %>`

Comment: Nicos Karalis question: "You want to grab a favicon from another site and make it yours?" - Answer: "No, I would like to refer to those favicons in order to build an HTML image tag".

Comment: do you mean build a mosaic image?

Comment: No, I mean to use that favicon just to put that near a web site name. Eg ('[fv]' represent the Facebook favicon): [fv] Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

The favicons are being found by two ways. First, there is a 'hardcoded', traditional name of `http://example.com/favicon.ico'.

Second, the HTML pages may define the favicon in their `<head>` sections, by `<link rel="icon"...>` and a few other. *(You may want to read the [Wikipedia article about favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Accessibility))*

So, your automat may fetch the main page of given website, parse it and check whether there are proper `<link>` tags, and then, as a fallback, try the "hardcoded" `favicon.ico` name.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a regular img tag with the src attribute pointing to the favicon?

```
<img src="http://www.facebook.com/favicon.icon">
```

This assumes a browser recognizes a .ico file as an image.  Helped methods would probably work with this too.

Comment: I think no because not all web sites have a favicon named exactly 'favicon.ico'. I would like to recognize that in an "automatic" way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with [pismo](https://github.com/peterc/pismo) gem.

Quick example to get the url of Facebook's favicon:

```
Pismo::Document.new('http://www.facebook.com/').favicon
```

Comment: I would like to implement my own code\solution as simple as possible.

Comment: Pismo is not maintained any more, and it does not allow `redirect`, see https://github.com/peterc/pismo/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

Here's my ruby method, that will strip the end off a URL, append the favicon, and produce an image tag.

```
  def favicon_for(url)
    matches = url.match(/[^:\/]\/(.*)/)
    image_tag url.sub(matches[1], '') + '/favicon.ico', {width: '16px', height: '16px'}
  end
```

Comment: Clever, but it's very common for websites to deviate from this pattern, so it's not usable.